# Perfect tense in Google Translate and DeepL

Tags: sentence-structure, perfect-tense

We have learned in A1 that if we want to make a sentence in a perfect tense, we should use *haben* followed by the verb in the past participle.
For example, the sentence

> We have made a bike tour.

reads in German:

> *Wir haben eine Radtour gemacht.*

However, both Google Translate and DeepL Translate returns

> > *Wir haben eine Radtour gemacht.*

as:

> > We made a bike tour.

which is a simple past tense.

What am I missing here?

Comment: *We made a bike tour* is unidiomatic and in fact [Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Wir%20haben%20eine%20Radtour%20gemacht.) gives the correct translation *we went for a bike ride*. - But why does it bother you that a **German** perfect can correspond to an **English** simple past? They're different languages.

Comment: @DavidVogt Thanks for your comment. I was confused because sometimes Google Translate and DeepL Translate give past tense and sometimes perfect tense.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for the link. It seems interesting, please let me read it.

Comment: While Google Translate is probably not that bad for German, [please understand that it's not perfect either](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perfect tense in English and perfect tense in German differ in meaning and usage.

The present perfect tense in English describes a past event that has present tense implications. The perfect in German simply describes past events, and can be used interchangeably with the past tense/preterite.

So, if you have a sentence in German which uses perfect tense to describe past events, but without expressing any implications for the present, using perfect tense in the English translation would be wrong. You have to use past tense.